# React navbar renders components separately with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom, tailwind-css, nav

I am using react router dom to render a website with react and tailwindcss. The navbar when clicked refreshes and renders the component on it's own without the other components. This is not what I want.

I want the components rendered in a single page in the way it is structured in my App.js file

I have tried using normal hrefs and now Link from react-router-dom, But I still get the same result

App.js

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="max-w-[1440px] mx-auto bg-page overflow-hidden relative">
      <Header />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Banner />} />
        <Route path="/home" element={<Banner />} />
        <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
        <Route path="/hero" element={<Hero />} />
        <Route path="/featured" element={<Featured />} />
        <Route path="/gallery" element={<GallerySection />} />
        <Route path="/testimonies" element={<Testimony />} />
        <Route path="/join" element={<Join />} />
        <Route path="/footer" element={<Footer />} />
        <Route path="/copy" element={<Copyright />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Index.js

```
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Router>
      <App />
    </Router>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Navbar.js

```
const Nav = () => {
  return (
    <nav className="hidden lg:flex">
      <ul className="flex gap-x-8 text-white">
        {["home", "about", "featured", "gallery", "testimonies", "join"].map(
          (item) => {
            return (
              <li key={`link-${item}`}>
                <Link to={`/${item}`} className="capitalize">
                  {item}
                </Link>
              </li>
            );
          }
        )}
      </ul>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Nav;
```

I would appreciate any help please

Comment: Have you tried using Outlet Component for nested routing?

Comment: You need to use browserRouter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use hashtags instead different routes.

So you have to use only one index route

```
<Route path="/" element={<IndexPage />} />
```

and render section components in `IndexPage` component one by one

```
const IndexPage = () => (
  <>
    <Banner />
    ...
  </>
)
```

then add into each section component wrapper `id` attribute

```
const Banner = () => (
  <div id="banner">
    ...content...
  </div>
)
```

and use hashtag links in you Nav component:

```
<Link to={`#${item}`} className="capitalize">
  {item}
</Link>
```

links will be looks like `domain.com/#banner` and if use open it then browser will scroll down to specific element with `id`

also I suggest to add some css to make scrolling smooth:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```